# How to set twitter app consumer credentials in amazon cognito via CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, twitter, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

Trying out this from the CLI

```
aws cognito-identity update-identity-pool \
--identity-pool-id MyIdentityPoolId \
--identity-pool-name MyIdentityPoolName \
--allow-unauthenticated-identities \
--supported-login-providers graph.facebook.com=MyFacebookAppId,api.twitter.com=MyTwitterConsumerKey;MyTwitterConsumerSecret \
--region $MyRegion
```

The CLI response says:

```
{
    "SupportedLoginProviders": {
        "api.twitter.com": "MyTwitterConsumerKey",
        "graph.facebook.com": "MyFacebookAppId"
    }, 
    "AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities": true, 
    "IdentityPoolName": "MyIdentityPoolName", 
    "IdentityPoolId": "MyIdentityPoolId"
}
MyTwitterConsumerSecret: command not found
```

Unlike configuring facebook (which requires only one credential (the FacebookAppId), configuring twitter requires 2 credentials (***ConsumerKey*** and ***ConsumerSecret***).

If i am delimiting the 2 credentials by a semi-colon, looks like only the first part is getting set in the twitter configuration for amazon cognito. ***Screenshot attached***.

[image: Twitter configuration for Amazon Cognito]

***What is the format to pass BOTH ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret for configuring twitter?***

---

I referred to these AWS docs:

- [Update Identity Pool via CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/update-identity-pool.html)
- [Create Identity Pool via CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/create-identity-pool.html)
- [Configuring Twitter/Digits with Amazon Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/twitter.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. How silly. Simply needed to scope the credentials for `--supported-login-providers` within double-quotes.

```
--supported-login-providers graph.facebook.com="MyFacebookAppId",api.twitter.com="MyTwitterConsumerKey;MyTwitterConsumerSecret"
```

Then it worked.

```
{
    "SupportedLoginProviders": {
        "api.twitter.com": "MyTwitterConsumerKey;MyTwitterConsumerSecret",
        "graph.facebook.com": "MyFacebookAppId"
    }, 
    "AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities": true, 
    "IdentityPoolName": "MyIdentityPoolName", 
    "IdentityPoolId": "MyIdentityPoolId"
}
```

Screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: `;` is a shell meta character and needs to be escaped to be literal. Putting it in double or single quotes will also treat it literally.